# Mobile Browser sends automatic GET Request, after terminating POST Response

Tags: post, get, httprequest

I have a really strange problem, when sending a POST Form from a "mobile Browser"

- the form is send to the Server with a POST request
- this works fine with desktop browser (Chrome,Safari,FF,IE)
- with a mobile Browser on the first try , the response get's terminate (browser sends FIN ACK and then multiple RSTs, debugged with Wireshark), and then the browser makes a GET request to the form endpoint (the form endpoint is not the same as the current site)
- if I send the form again from the same session it works fine on mobile
- I tested this with real mobile clients (iPhone,iPad,Android Phone) and also get same behavior when I emulate a mobile device with the Chrome Dev Tools

Any Idea what this could be?

Thx

Answer (score 0):

This is fairly standard client behavior: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get
It exists to prevent double-posting of HTML Forms.

You can use this behavior in certain situations (APIs: latest comments, change current language translation), like when one needs to force a browser to refresh the resource even though the URI hasn't changed. You can POST to the URI and then the browser should send an automatic GET, which will update the browser's cached response.